# Sharing Google Sheet with service account not working (Delivery Status Notification (Failure))

Tags: python-3.x, google-api, google-oauth

I'm trying to read data from a Google Sheet in my Google Drive, and keep getting an email saying my service account address couldn't be found -

[image: email screenshot]

I tried following 2 walk-thrus - [this one](https://towardsdatascience.com/accessing-google-spreadsheet-data-using-python-90a5bc214fd2) and [that one](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/02/an-easy-way-to-read-and-write-to-a-google-spreadsheet-in-python.html), which are pretty similar.  In both cases I followed all steps, including creating new project, enabling Google Drive API, creating credentials (a Web Server to access Application Data, granted it a Project Role of Editor), downloading the JSON, and trying to share the sheet with the client_email in the JSON.  The structure of the address also checks out - **[service_account_name]@[my_project].iam.gserviceaccount.com**.

I also triple checked the sheet is on the same account as my API project.

Still, I keep getting this email saying the domain can't be found, and when I try accessing the sheet in my code, I'm getting a 403 - Insufficient Permission error.

Any suggestions?

Comment: were you able to find an answer? I'm also stuck with this problem right now

Comment: please post the answer if u knew the solution , stuck on the same page